# Illegal string offset Undefined offset: 2

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php\mysql and I'm having issuing querying my database and formulating a top 10 list of users arranged by the column 'points'.

**The error:** Illegal string offset 'username'
Illegal string offset 'points'
Illegal string offset 'username'
Illegal string offset 'points'
Undefined offset: 2
Undefined offset: 2
Undefined offset: 3
Undefined offset: 3
Points: c c points1 1 points points points

My current mysql query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, points FROM users ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10")
or die(mysql_error());

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$top10 = "Points: ";
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
{
$top10 .= $rows[$i]['points']." ".$rows[$i]['username']." points";
}
echo $top10;
```

Comment: use mysql_fetch_all instead of array.thiis would put all the data into an array else you have to loop over the result and put them in an array

Comment: You get an array  which you can loop over with any for loop and try using associative array whiile fetching data instead of numeric.

Comment: Are you using php to display the data or is this ajax

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array). Put it under your pillow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, points FROM users ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10")
or die(mysql_error());
$top10 = "Points: ";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $top10 .= $row[0]." ".$row[1]." points";
}
echo $top10;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_all()  any idea why?

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT username, points FROM users ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10")
or die(mysql_error());

$rows=mysql_fetch_all($result);
$top10 = "Points: ";
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
{
    $top10 .= $rows[$i]['points']." ".$rows[$i]['username']." points";
}
echo $top10;

Comment: do it mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysql_fetch_all

Comment: Illegal string offset 'username'
Illegal string offset 'points'
Illegal string offset 'username'
Illegal string offset 'points'
Undefined offset: 2
Undefined offset: 2
Undefined offset: 3
Undefined offset: 3
Points: c c points1 1 points points points

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

In this line you are assigning the first row of the data array to `$row`.

you can check the structure of $row by the function `print_r`. 
Try `print_r($row)`.

To access a column in that row use the db table's column name as index. like `$row['ColumnName']`; if you print this with `"echo $row['column name']"` you will get the value of the column that has been fetched.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your answer

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['points'];
}
```

The same using fetch_all

```
$rows=mysql_fetch_all($result);
for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++)
{
    echo $rows[$i]['username'];
    echo $rows[$i]['points'];
}
```

Comment: Read the documentaion of these functions you will get a detailed idea about what each function does http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php